# WCAG 2.0 and ATAG together

Tags: accessibility, w3c, wcag, wcag2.0, atag

I am bit confused about **ATAG** and **WCAG 2.0**.

I was wondering if it is ever appropriate to use both ATAG and WCAG for one system?

Answer (score 8):

**WCAG** provides guidelines for **Web content**: *How can I make my Web content accessible?*

**ATAG** provides guidelines for **Web authoring tools**: *How can I make my Web authoring tool accessible, and how can I make sure that it produces accessible content?*

ATAG relies on and references guidelines from WCAG. So whenever you need ATAG, you’ll most likely also need WCAG.

Related page from the Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI): [Essential Components of Web Accessibility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/components.php)

Answer (score 1):

ATAG stands for Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines. They provide guidelines for DESIGNING web content authoring tools that are both more accessible to authors with disabilities and designed to enable, support, and promote the production of more accessible web content by all authors. ATAG applies to Content Management System (CMS), any website which you can create content or the admin section of your website.

WCAG stands for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines. It covers a wide range of recommendations for making Web content more accessible.  WCAG applies to any web content on a website.